# Nested for loop output not correct

Tags: java

```
 for(int c = 1; c <= rows; c++) {
      for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
          System.out.print(++number + " ");
      }
 }
```

let us assume that rows = 5 and number = 0 initially. what will be the output?

to me, if rows were 5, the output would be as follows: 
1
2
3
4
5

however my teacher has it as: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

and i can't seem to wrap my head around it! can anyone explain why ? i have tried with different numbers as well, for 2, i would get just the number 1,2 but my professor gets 1,2,3

Comment: I suggest you get a pen and paper and write down the output

Comment: Or run in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every row with the inner loop execute `System.out.print(++number + " ");` this statement total `15(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)` times and every time number value is implemented and print.

Take a look visualization [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=public%20class%20YourClassNameHere%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20void%20main%28String%5B%5D%20args%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20int%20rows%3D5,number%3D0%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28int%20c%20%3D%201%3B%20c%20%3C%3D%20rows%3B%20c%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28int%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20c%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.out.print%28%2B%2Bnumber%20%2B%20%22%20%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=java&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: I added a visualization hope it helps

Comment: this visual helped so much in my understanding! thank you so much! happy coding my friend!

Answer (score 2):

You have two nested loops.

The outer loop iterates from `1` to `5`.

The inner loop iterates from `0` to `c - 1`.

When `c == 1`, the inner loop iterates from 0 to 0 so `number` is incremented 1 time.

When `c == 2`, the inner loop iterates from 0 to 1 so `number` is incremented 2 times.

When `c == 3`, the inner loop iterates from 0 to 2 so `number` is incremented 3 times.

When `c == 4`, the inner loop iterates from 0 to 3 so `number` is incremented 4 times.

When `c == 5`, the inner loop iterates from 0 to 4 so `number` is incremented 5 times.

In total, `number` is incremented 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 == 15 times.

Each time `number` is incremented, it is also printed, followed by a space. So the loops produce the output `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`.

Comment: well, what i meant was that the print statement prints out the numbers 1-15. i get that you can add them together, but i don't get how thats the output

Comment: @waifu_nom each time `number` is incremented, it is also printed. So the incremented value (1, 2, 3, ..., 15) is printed.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to understand this type of problems is dry-run. I am sharing a two step dry-run hoping that will be helpful:
[dry-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xeeu.png)